# click on a button then all similar buttons clicked

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, add-on

Im working with a burse website so sometimes i want to purchase a share , so i want to purchase more than 1 share.
 but i haven't more time "I have less than 1 second' , then i open more than 1 page and i choose my parchases.
 but when i click on number 1 to purchase then I don't have a time to click to others, so I want to click number 1 button then anothers button automatically clicked.
I wanna click on a button then another buttons clicked.
let me to find a way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to click a button which will trigger click event on other buttons, you can use the jQuery **trigger** function.
The following script from jquery documentation does the same thing, here clicking 1st button does usual call to update method for itself. But clicking the 2nd button makes the 1st button also clicked and hence call update method for both 1st and 2nd buttons.

i.e. *click on 2nd button triggers click event on 1st button*.

> $( "button:first" ).click(function() {
>    update( $( "span:first" ) );
>   });
>
> $( "button:last" ).click(function() {
>    $( "button:first" ).trigger( "click" );
>    update( $( "span:last" ) );
>   });
>
> function update( j ) {
>    var n = parseInt( j.text(), 10 );
>    j.text( n + 1 );
>   }

Comment: dear mukul. I dont write code to target website. imagine you want to buy more than 1 item on a website like amazon.com (but my target website is burse website) so how to can you buy more than 1 item (isnt similar- example t-shirt ,hat,glasses) , you know you cant click all of them as same as time. you need more than 1 second to click all of them.(in burse website you haven't any time to buy purchases more than some second) , so I open all pages and at a defined time I must click all them, but I dont. you have any ideas? (extra info: burse website isn't mine )